# Creating ESlint warning for function

Tags: eslint

I have a function where one of the arguments (`b`) should only be used in a specific use-case. I would like to give the developer a warning if the argument is used.

```
const myFn = (a: boolean, b: boolean) => {}
```

I wondered if you could define inline rules, something like this:

```js
/*eslint b !== undefined: 1 "Don't use this argument unless....." */
const myFn = (a: boolean, b: boolean) => {}
```

Or how can I achieve this?

Comment: I think you need to create your own custom ESLint plugin to do that

Comment: Yeah that was kinda my question; how you would go about that. I guess my communication skills were just rubbish as per usual. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Custom ELint Rules - you cant do it as simply as you suggest (not inline), but check out this:

[https://www.kenneth-truyers.net/2016/05/27/writing-custom-eslint-rules/#:~:text=In%20order%20to%20write%20a,must%20start%20with%20eslint%2Dplugin](https://www.kenneth-truyers.net/2016/05/27/writing-custom-eslint-rules/#:%7E:text=In%20order%20to%20write%20a,must%20start%20with%20eslint%2Dplugin)

Comment: Thanks. Finally an article where I understand it. :)